# Passport JS | Get access token using authorization code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I am new in Node.js. I am using express, passport, passport-oauth2 strategy for authentication for my react application.

1. My react application is running on 'https//localhost:8060'
2. My Passport.js auth service is running on 'http://localhost:8080'

Below is the passport.js strategy configuration present in my node service index.js

```
passport.use(
new OAuth2Strategy(
    {
        authorizationURL: 'https://idp-portal-URL', // IDP portal url
        tokenURL: 'https://token.oauth2', // token URL
        callbackURL: 'https://localhost:8060/auth', // **REACT application call back URL**
        clientID: clientCreds.clientID,
        clientSecret: clientCreds.clientSecret,
        scope: 'openid profile',
    },
    function(accessken, refreshToken, user, profile, done) {
        const ca = user.id_token;
        return done(null, user);
    },
),
```

);

Then authenticating below route: This is route which i am calling from my React application e.g: 'http://localhost:8080/login'

```
app.get(
'/login',
passport.authenticate('oauth2', { failureRedirect: '/failed' }),
function(req, res, next) {
    next();
    const config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: `https://idp-a/authorization.oauth2?token=${req.user.access_token}`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        data: {
            client_id: clientCreds.clientID,
            client_secret: clientCreds.clientSecret
        },
    };
    axios(config)
        .then(function(response) {
            res.redirect(`https://localhost:8060/#/auth?ssoParams=${queryParam}`);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
},
```

);

with this above code user able to successfully authenticate and redirecting back to my react application URL which is configured in as callback URL with appending auth code in query param. like below:
"https://localhost:8060/auth?code=***************"

**But before that in node service itself I want to retrieve access token using the auth code received in query param.**

How can I retrieve access token using auth code by making API call and then redirect back to my react application with access code. The axios call which I wrote in call back function is not executing and nothing printing in console or no error.

Please help here, will appreciate your help.